# SQL 2012 query performance

Tags: execution, optimization

I have a SQL table with approximately 80 million rows. Columns first name and last name are full text indexed. Also we have appropriate clustered and non clustered indexes.

We have different types of queries and everything works fine regarding performance and response time. but we have few cases when we are searching for specific first and last name in some time period and response time is few minutes (normally is 3-10 seconds).

When I look at the execution plan I see that there is index eager spool step and it costs 90%. before that step I have full text step. So I we cant figure out why we have good response time on million other combinations, (between in that queries we don't have eager spool step) but in this specific combination (first and last name, and they are very common) we have this issue.

I am using MS SQL Server 2012.

Comment: If you add in the table structure and the SQL query/queries), this question might be on-topic at the CodeReview Stack Exchange site. As it is, however, this question is Off-Topic here, because you're asking about code *performance* rather than a problem with non-working code, and your exact question is also unclear.

Comment: Could possible be parameter sniffing issues.